# how to access the values of the array

Tags: cakephp

I have been trying to access the values of the the array .. in the foreach loop but no luck, the first two calls get the values, but the ones in the foreach loop nothing.. comes empty although if i print the array all the values are there.

Comment: You should make sure you're using proper naming conventions, you'll stay out of trouble a lot better using them.

http://book.cakephp.org/view/902/File-and-Classname-Conventions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never actually access the $dish variable in the foreach loop.
Try

```
$dish['Dish']['dish_name'];
```

instead of

```
$dishes['Dish']['dish_name'];
```

etc.

Additionally, you will get an error because the first element in your array is not a Dish, its a Dish_Category. Thus, either remove this element from the array, or use a simple if statement before you access the $dish such as:

```
if($dish['dish_name']) 
    //DO STUFF HERE
```

Also, there is no reason for so many

```
<?php ?>
```

tags. Couldn't you put the whole block of code in one?

Comment: Actually I tried that before and I got this error Notice (8): Undefined index:  Dish [APP\views\dish_categories\get_categories.ctp, line 26]

Notice (8): Undefined index: Dish [APP\views\dish_categories\get_categories.ctp, line 30]' />

Comment: Are you sure 'Dish' is an index of the associative arrays in $dish? Perhaps you just mean to do $dish['dish_name']

Comment: I am going to post what the array displays

Comment: Ok i added it at the top please see

Comment: check the edits, the problem is that the first element accessed by your foreach loop is not a dish, but a [DishCategory] which does not have a "dish_name" field.

Comment: I am new to cake php, i still have problem accessing that second part.. thank you for all the help anyways

Comment: coudnt make it work but gave you the answer for trying to help me thank you